# How can I use a Azure AD Service Principal to connect an Azure DevOps pipeline to an artifact feed?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following scenario. I currently have a Nuget Artifact feed that I want to pull from in an Azure DevOps pipeline. The feed is in one DevOps organisation and my pipeline is in another DevOps organisation.

I currently have the following setup which works fine:

```
- job: build
    displayName: 'Build'
    steps:
    - task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
      inputs:
        nugetServiceConnections: ${{parameters.myArtifactFeed}}
```

I can then run tasks in later steps that restore packages. The service connection it uses ***myArtifactFeed*** is a NuGet type service connection that uses the authentication method *External Azure DevOps Server*, which I just provide a PAT for.

What I want to do is not use PAT's anymore.After reading this article, I thought I would be able to create a service principal in Entra ID, add it to my org, give it read permission to my artifact feed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops

But this doesn't seem to work and I can't find any documentation on how to do this.

TL:DR - How can create a Azure DevOps Service Connection which uses an Azure Service Principal credentials as it's auth, which can then be used in a NuGetAuthenticate@0 Azure DevOps pipeline task to restore packages.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a NuGet service connection using an Azure Service Principal, you need to generate an Entra ID token for this Service Principal. Run the following PowerShell scripts to get the token.

```
$TenantId = "***"
$ApplicationId = "***"
$ClientSecret = "***"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "$ClientSecret" -AsPlainText -Force
$pscredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ApplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $pscredential -TenantId $TenantId -ServicePrincipal
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798").Token
```

Then add the Entra ID token to Personal Access Token when you create a NuGet service connection.
[image]

It is not recommended to use Entra ID token instead of PAT in NuGet service connection. Because Entra ID tokens expire every hour and must be regenerated with a refresh token to get a new access token, you will need to create a new NuGet service connection every time Entra ID tokens expire.